# Is it possible to use Chart.js in web2py?

Tags: chart.js, web2py

I'm struggling with an application in web2py. I need to include a chart element (a radar chart), and tried many options, with no success. Then I decided to use Chart.bundle.js by adding the script in the view and stored the file Chart.bundle.js in the static directory.

But it is not working. I get none error, but the chart is not being loaded in the view.
Following is the view code:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}

<html>
<head>

<script src='static/Chart.bundle.js'></script>

</head>

<body>

<br>

<div id="wrapper">
  <canvas id="chartjs-radar" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var presets = window.chartColors;
        var utils = Samples.utils;

        var data = {
            labels: {{=areaslist}},
            datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: utils.transparentize(presets.red),
                borderColor: presets.red,
                data: {{=calcperarea}},
                label: 'Digital Maturity Assessment'
            }]
        };

        var options = {
            maintainAspectRatio: true,
            spanGaps: false,
            elements: {
                line: {
                    tension: 0.000001
                }
            }
        };

        var chart = new Chart('chartjs-radar', {
            type: 'radar',
            data: data,
            options: options
        });

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src='static/Chart.bundle.js'></script>
```

Check the network tab of the browser developer tools to see if Chart.bundle.js is loading. Likely you are getting a 404 response, as the above URL is a relative URL and will be appended to the URL of the parent page. You should instead use the web2py `URL` helper to generate all internal URLs:

```
<script src="{{=URL('static', 'Chart.bundle.js')}}"></script>
```

The above should generate a URL like `/appname/static/Chart.bundle.js` (`appname` will be excluded if you have routing configured to default to this app).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Anthony. That's exactly what I did, and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create it on a wrong way, you can't just specify chart id and use it. What you need is `ctx`, context of your canvas element. See how you can use it:

```
$("#chartjs-radar").get(0).getContext('2d');
```

or

```
document.getElementById('chartjs-radar').getContext('2d');
```

Use this instead of id while creating chart. (Then you can use just chart.js, not bundle)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alien.